# Using Chained Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, chained

I am trying to use the remote Chained plugin in CakePhp (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)
I used Jquery to test an alert and that works but just the chained plugin is not working. I am trying to follow the example on their website using their code. If you want to view my page go to http://team.southpacificavionics.com/customers/test
login: guest
password: password

jquery.chained.remote.min.js

```
/*! Chained 1.0.0 - MIT license - Copyright 2010-2014 Mika Tuupola */
!function(a){"use strict";a.fn.remoteChained=function(b){var c=a.extend({},a.fn.remoteChained.defaults,b);return c.loading&&(c.clear=!0),this.each(function(){function b(b){var c=a(":selected",d).val();a("option",d).remove();var e=[];if(a.isArray(b))e=a.isArray(b[0])?b:a.map(b,function(b){return a.map(b,function(a,b){return[[b,a]]})});else for(var f in b)b.hasOwnProperty(f)&&e.push([f,b[f]]);for(var g=0;g!==e.length;g++){var h=e[g][0],i=e[g][1];if("selected"!==h){var j=a("<option />").val(h).append(i);a(d).append(j)}else c=i}a(d).children().each(function(){a(this).val()===c+""&&a(this).attr("selected","selected")}),1===a("option",d).size()&&""===a(d).val()?a(d).prop("disabled",!0):a(d).prop("disabled",!1)}var d=this,e=!1;a(c.parents).each(function(){a(this).bind("change",function(){var f={};a(c.parents).each(function(){var b=a(this).attr(c.attribute),e=(a(this).is("select")?a(":selected",this):a(this)).val();f[b]=e,c.depends&&a(c.depends).each(function(){if(d!==this){var b=a(this).attr(c.attribute),e=a(this).val();f[b]=e}})}),e&&a.isFunction(e.abort)&&(e.abort(),e=!1),c.clear&&(c.loading?b.call(d,{"":c.loading}):a("option",d).remove(),a(d).trigger("change")),e=a.getJSON(c.url,f,function(c){b.call(d,c),a(d).trigger("change")})}),c.bootstrap&&(b.call(d,c.bootstrap),c.bootstrap=null)})})},a.fn.remoteChainedTo=a.fn.remoteChained,a.fn.remoteChained.defaults={attribute:"name",depends:null,bootstrap:null,loading:null,clear:!1}}(window.jQuery||window.Zepto,window,document);
```

test.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.chained.remote.min'); ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('java is working');
    });
</script>

<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
  <option value="series-5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
  <option value="series-6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
  <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
  <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
  <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
</select>

<script>
(function() { 
    $("#series").chainedTo("#mark");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CakePHP really - it's a client-side javascript library.

But you have two problems, first:

```
(function() { 
    $("#series").chainedTo("#mark");
});
```

Is not actually "running", you just defined an anonymous function that *would* run, if called. It should just be moved, probably, to where you're `alert` resides:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#series").chainedTo("#mark");
    });
</script>
```

Now it'll run, but if you checked the browser Console, it'll be erroring out, something like:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chainedTo is not a function

It looks like the library isn't running correctly.

I'm not sure where you got the source code for the jquery chained library, but it's not the current version in the page you link's github grab it from:

> https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/

A direct minimized version is listed here:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/master/jquery.chained.min.js

Comment: Wow thanks so much I included all the files from https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/
and just included these too scrips
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.chained'); ?>